# How to conditionally create trigger if it does not exist in HSQLDB?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

HSQLDB supports conditionally creating a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable
```

But this syntax is unfortunately not supported for triggers. If we try to create a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT ...
```

there will be an 'object name already exists' error if we have created it before.
What would be the current workaround to be able to

1. create the trigger when it does not exist yet and
2. do not get an error when it exists already ?

I can check if the trigger exists with this select:

```
SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = 'MYTRIGGER')
```

but not sure how I can use this to conditionally perform the create trigger statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_exists
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
 WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = 'MYTRIGGER';

IF (v_exists = 0) THEN -- Does not exists
  CREATE TRIGGER ....
END IF;
```

Comment: I'm getting 'unexpected token IF' ?